# Apache Spark job failed with FileNotFoundExceptoin

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

I have a `spark` cluster consists of 5 nodes and I have a spark job written in Java that read set of files from a directory and send the content to `Kafka`.

When I was testing the job locally, everything was working fine.

When I tried to submit the job to the cluster, the job failed with `FileNoTFoundException`

The files need to be processed exists in a directory mounted on all the 5 nodes so I am sure the file path appears in the exception exists.

Here is the exception appears while submitting the job

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/me/shared/input_1.txt does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:534)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:747)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:524)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:409)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:766)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.<init>(LineRecordReader.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:67)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:216)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The directory `/home/me/shared/` is mounted on all the 5 nodes.

EDIT:

Here is the command I am using to submit the job

```
bin$ ./spark-submit --total-executor-cores 20 --executor-memory 5G --class org.company.java.FileMigration.FileSparkMigrator --master spark://spark-master:7077 /home/me/FileMigrator-0.1.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar /home/me/shared kafka01,kafka02,kafka03,kafka04,kafka05 kafka_topic
```

I faced a weird behavior. I submitted the job while the directory contains only one file, the exception is thrown on the driver but the file is processed successfully. Then, I added another file, the same behavior occurred. But, once I added the third file, the exception is thrown and the job failed.

### EDIT 2

### After some tries, we discovered that there was a problem in the mounted directory that caused this weird behavior.

Comment: Does the spark application user have permissions to the those mounted directories?

Comment: yes, there is no problem in the permissions

Answer (score 1):

Spark defaults to HDFS by default.  This looks like an NFS file, so try to access it with: `file:///home/me/shared/input_1.txt`

Yes, three `/`!

Comment: Actually, there are many files in the directory /home/me/shared/ and I want to process them all. So, in the code, I am using context.textFile("/home/me/shared/*"); Does your answer still valid?

Comment: Yep!  try `context.textFile("file:///home/me/shared/*");`

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work. There is a weird behavior happen. I tested the same job and the directory was containing only one file.  The same exception is thrown while submitting the job but it continued to work and the file is processed successfully. Then added another file, restart the job and it worked fine. Once I added the third file, the job failed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what solve the problem for me. It is weird and I have no idea what the actual problem was.

Simply I asked the sysadmin to mount another directory instead of the one I was using. After that, everything worked fine.

Is seems there was an issue in the old mounted directory but I have no idea what was the actual problem.